# Is it a way to create CloudKit account based on Facebook login button?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

The issue with CloudKit web services is the **authentication**. Who use CloudKit from browser or from a web component on Android, will not have Apple ID, so they have to go though the registration process.

1. choose Apple ID
2. set birthday
3. set first / last name
4. optionally set an e-mail
5. set three control questions for remembering (!!!)

It totally breaks the workflow on web and Android. Nowadays people don't waste time register on a site, especially when registration is so long.

Any way to register an Apple ID based on FaceBook login button?

Comment: Apple would have to build in support for that functionality and they haven't so this is currently not possible and I doubt it'll be possible in the future. Sounds like you probably want to use something other than CloudKit, like Parse.

Comment: Parse .. are you kidding? ..